# Friend function from a templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, friend

I have a class like this:

```
#include "Blarg.h"
// ...

class Foo : public Bar {    
  // ...
  static double m_value;
  // ...    
};
```

And another one like this:

```
template<class X, class Y>
class Blarg : public Bar {
  // ...
  void SetValue(double _val) { Foo::m_value = _val; }
  // ...
};
```

Since `Foo`'s `m_value` is private (and I would like to keep it that way), I thought I would declare the `SetValue` function as a friend to the `Foo` class so that it could access the static member when needed.

I've tried declarations along these lines within `Foo`'s public area:

```
template<class X, class Y> friend void Blarg<X, Y>::SetValue(double _val);

template<class X, class Y> friend void Blarg::SetValue(double _val);

friend void Blarg::SetValue(double _val);
```

...but no luck in compiling. What is the proper syntax for this, if possible?

Comment: What error do you get with the first one?

Comment: "no luck in compiling" is not a technical description of the error you have faced.

Comment: You need to write a `;` after each class definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define `Blarg` class before `Foo` class in order to mark one of `Blarg`'s method as a `friend`. Are sure the `Blarg` is defined (or included) before `Foo` declaration with a friend line?

Comment: That and fix the member function's types (return type is missing). +1

Comment: ^Oops! Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
template<class X, class Y>
class Blarg : public Bar {
    public:
        void SetValue(double _val);
};

class Foo : public Bar {
    private:
        static double m_value;

    public:
        template<class X, class Y> friend void Blarg<X,Y>::SetValue(double _val);
};

template <class X, class Y>
void Blarg<X,Y>::SetValue(double _val)
{
    Foo::m_value = _val;
}
```

I had to break the circular dependency by defining Blarg first and making SetValue not inline. Your friend declaration was pretty much correct, except for the missing return value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct syntax:

```
template<class T>
class Bla
{
 public:
  void toto(double val);
};    

class Foo {
  static double m_value;
  template<typename T>
  friend void Bla<T>::toto (double);
} ;
```

Also, make sure that `Bla` is defined before `Foo`.